# Emacs flymake prevents loading of files when directory is not writeable

Tags: emacs, flymake

When I open a file in a directory that is not writeable I get

```
Opening output file: Permission denied, /path/to/file
```

At the same time the file is not loaded.

When I repeat the `find-file` command, the file is loaded fine the second time.

The functionality I would like is: open the file right away and maybe show a message that flymake can't work but stay out of the way.

I already have set `flymake-gui-warnings-enabled` to `nil` which at least rids me of the annoying dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could configure flymake to not start syntax checking when loading the file (i always do that just to speed things up).

```
(setq flymake-start-syntax-check-on-find-file nil)
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, so then it will only start when the file is edited or manually?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely caused by the fact that Flymake attempts to write a temporary copy of your buffer to the same directory as the original file.

You can avoid that by following the steps in this blog:

http://blog.urth.org/2011/06/flymake-versus-the-catalyst-restarter.html

That solves the issue for Perl, but can be adapted for other languages fairly easily, or you can download a patched version of flymake.el from https://github.com/illusori/emacs-flymake which patches this issue and a few others. (Full disclosure: I'm the author of the patch.)